# Solving $\tan(\frac\pi4 \left(4x-5\right))=-1$. Rewriting $-1$ as $\tan\frac\pi4$ vs $\tan\frac{3\pi}{4}$ gives different answers.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm solving this equation:
$$\tan \left(\frac{\pi \left(4x-5\right)}{4}\right)=-1$$

When I rewrite $-1$ as $-\tan\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$, I get $x=1+n$,
but when I change $-1$ for $\tan \left(\frac{3\pi }{4}\right)$, I get $x=2+n$.

What is it I do wrong?

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong: the solution set for $x$ is simply all of the integers $\Bbb Z$; in the solution $x=1+n$, the $n$ is an arbitrary integer, so the expression $1+n$ and $2+n$ both represent an arbitrary integer. It's kind of like the constant of integration you encounter when learning calculus: $x^2$ and $x^2+2$ are both antiderivatives of $2x$: the entire family of antiderivatives being $x^2+c$ for some arbitrary constant $c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ are any integers then $x=1+n$ and $x=2+n$ define the same solution sets, just written differently.  You could even say $x = n$ and that would still define the same solution set.